# In Indesign, how to apply one master page to all first pages of documents?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I want to apply a master page to all the first pages of the documents in a indesign book.

I have typed out the chapters of a book as separate documents and have made an InDesign book into which I have arranged them in the correct order. As the first page contains the title of the chapter, it has a separate master page. Right now I am applying the correct master page to every document manually.

Is it possible to automatically apply a specific master page to the first pages of all documents?

Comment: Documents in a book? Documents sitting on your hard drive?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more detail so we can better help you but at this time I have closed it because it is unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Matt is the question clear now?

Comment: It's possible to do with a custom written script, but unless you got a *lot* of documents, it may be easier and faster to do it by hand.

Comment: Pages Panel Menu > Apply Master to pages....

Comment: @Scott: yep, I have assigned a shortcut to that. A win for the Windows version: you can tab to the dropdown list and select by *letter*!